# Python PyPDF2 add table of contents

Tags: python, pypdf

I've been able to use PyPDF2 to combine a PDF and create bookmarks. Is there anyway to use PyPDF2 to also add a hyperlinked table of contents page to the combined file?

Thanks for the response. Using your suggestion I can create a ToC which can then be merged with my PDF, however the problem is that internal links in the ToC to pages that don't yet exist cause errors.

Here's the code:

```
from fpdf import FPDF

pdf = FPDF()
pdf.set_font("helvetica", size=24)
pdf.add_page()
link = pdf.add_link(page=3)
pdf.cell(text="Internal link to first page", border=0, link=link,ln=2)
link = pdf.add_link(page=4)
pdf.cell(ln=1,text="Internal link to first page", border=0, link=link)
pdf.output("C:/cont/hyperlink1.pdf")
```

This causes the following error:

File "C:\Users\andre\anaconda\lib\site-packages\fpdf\output.py", line 416, in bufferize
f"Invalid reference to non-existing page {dest.page_number} present on page {page_obj.index()}: "

ValueError: Invalid reference to non-existing page 3 present on page 1:

Answer (score 0):

PyPDF2 is deprecated. Use `pypdf`.

You can use a combination of `pypdf` and [`fpdf2`](https://pypi.org/project/fpdf2/) to create it:

1. Create a single (or multiple) pages that contain the text of the table of contents (ToC) with `fpdf2`
2. Use `pypdf` to merge the ToC into the original document
3. Add [`Link` annotations](https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/adding-pdf-annotations.html#link) via pypdf

Please note that you still need to know how the ToC should look like and where it should link to.

Please also note that `pypdf` and `fpdf2` are both in the `py-pdf` organization. The projects are still distinct, but we support each other (big kudos to LucasC who is the maintainer of fpdf2 and improved pypdf a lot).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've managed to use pdfp2 to create a new PDF that includes internal links. I can then use PyPDF to combine this ToC with my existing PDF. The problem is that I can't create internal links to pages that don't yet exist.

Comment: Did you follow the three steps I described in the order I wrote them?

Comment: I am still stuck on the last step since I need to know _where_ in the page to place the rectangles with the link annotations.
Am I missing something obvious here? Is there an easy way to know where each piece of text in the table of contents has ended up?

Comment: When you [add the text via fpdf2](https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/text/index.html) you need to give the coordinates. Have you tried using those for adding the link annotation as well?